# How to create a GCC Bugzilla account

Tags: gcc

I found g++ internal compiler error, and I tried to send a bug report to GCC Bugzilla.

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/

But user account creation has been restricted.
How can I report them the error?

Comment: I sympathize but this question does not present any programming problem so it is off-topic on SO. You should follow the advice on [account-creation page](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/createaccount.cgi) and email  overseers@gcc.gnu.org.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming within Stackoverflow's terms.

Comment: What part of the [create account](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/createaccount.cgi) page is not clear?  "Because of spam, account creation through this form is restricted. If creating an account fails, contact gcc-bugzilla-account-request at gcc dot gnu dot org to request a GCC Bugzilla account. You should receive a response within 24 hours."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions are provided in the [create account page](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/createaccount.cgi): "Because of spam, account creation through this form is restricted. If creating an account fails, contact gcc-bugzilla-account-request at gcc dot gnu dot org to request a GCC Bugzilla account. You should receive a response within 24 hours."

As a side note, unless your bug reproduces with recent GCC (say 6.x) and you have a minial reprocase I wouldn't bother reporting it.

Comment: No, that's not the right answer. The [create account](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/createaccount.cgi) page is clear what to do: _"Because of spam, account creation through this form is restricted. If creating an account fails, contact gcc-bugzilla-account-request at gcc dot gnu dot org to request a GCC Bugzilla account. You should receive a response within 24 hours."_